# Greek characters read with UTF8 charset are printed as ����

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to read a file containing greek words in utf8
with the following code

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
  tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);
  while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    currentToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
    map.put(currentToken, 1);
  }
}
```

On every forum I looked for, I saw this `new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8")`
but still the printed results is like that `����`

p.s. when i print a variable containing a greek word from inside the code, the print is successfull, that means that the problem is on file read.

any ideas?

Comment: Does using UTF-8 instead of UTF8 help anything? --> Apparently not

Comment: Does it work if you create the `BufferedReader` using [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)?

Comment: unfortunately neither of the ideas work

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* the file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: yes, the file is UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Did you look at the strings being returned by `reader.readLine()` to make sure they are correct?  What is `map`? And exactly how are you printing results?  I suspect this is likely a display issue rather than a reading issue.

Comment: ignore everything inside the first `while` and replace them with a `print(line)` . The output is `����`

Answer (score 2):

There are some with too professionalism here. I remind you again that we are humans, not compilers! I am here again "powers" you deleted by post! I am very proud of being born in the birthplace of democracy, respecting the other discussants! You don't respect anything "guru" guys...

PS: Yeah, I know that you disseminate again down votes, but who really cares?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "UTF8" charset in Java. The correct charset name is "UTF-8":

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))
```

Or use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) instead to avoid any ambiguity:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

That being said, make sure the file is actually UTF-8 encoded.  If it has a UTF-8 BOM in front, you will have to either strip it off from the file itself, or manually skip it when reading the file before then reading the lines.  Java readers do not recognize or skip BOMs automatically.

Comment: as previously mentioned in a comment, this did not work either

Answer (score 1):

Use this for proper converstion - this one is from iso-8859-1 to utf-8:

```
public String to_utf8(String fieldvalue) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        String fieldvalue_utf8 = new String(fieldvalue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        return fieldvalue_utf8;
}
```